# CSPRNG output as stream cipher

Tags: random-number-generator

Say I want to encrypt short messages via radio to a friend. Would a series of key streams based on 36 characters (alphanumerics) generated by a CSPRNG like CryptGenRand and applied to the plain text provide adequate unpredictability? As with a OTP, each message would use a different stream.
My (limited) understanding here is that because the computer that generates the key stream is independent of the transmission method (radio) that attackers would either 1) have additional problems of identifying who I am, what computer I used, when I used it and gain access to this computer to get my key stream, or 2) have to crack the CSPRNG (possible, considering: http://eprint.iacr.org/2007/419.pdf).

Amplification: to answer some questions. Yes, it'd be Windows' CryptGenRandom (sorry, was a little off on the class name), probably by using SecureRandom class in Java. The output key streams would be generated on one pc, then shared via removable media. The actual encryption/decryption would be simple transposition using the key stream, and would be automated with a small app.

Comment: Is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379942(v=vs.85).aspx) the function you are talking about using? Are you sure that you can even decrypt? You can pass a seed to CryptGenRandom, but I think it still uses system entropy. Your friend will not have access to your system entropy, so they cannot decrypt your message.

Comment: Are you aiming to encrypt data by hand or computer is always given for both parties? If computer, use any typical cipher, if not, use OTP.

Comment: Just slightly off-topic, but it's worth noting that in the USA, it's against FCC regulations for amateur radio operators to encrypt their communications.

Comment: Luis, aware of that, this is hypothetical in nature. :)

Comment: Added some amplifying info to answer @mikea

Comment: @thebaker, when you say "simple transposition" what do you mean? Are you using XOR? Also, how long is the stream you are generating? Is it as long as the message?

Comment: @mikeazo, not xor, instead modular arithmetic. The stream would be as long as the message. Btw, I tried xor and it introduced non-alphanumeric characters that I didn't really want, given the medium. Read elsewhere that mod arithmetic shouldn't be less secure, just less computationally efficient.

Comment: @thebaker, what modulus are you using?

Comment: @mikeazo, mod 36 (based on a alphanumeric alphabet). Also, I just realized that I said 'transposition' when I meant 'substitution'.